# Point of Intersection Linear Systems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Need help here on dealing with the fractions. I need to find the point of intersection using substitute method.
\begin{align}
y&= \frac{1}{2}x - 2\\
y&= \frac{3}{4}x + 3\\
\end{align}
Initial step of solution:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}x-2 &= \frac{3}{4}x+3
\end{align}

What must I do next to find the X int?

Just edited, sorry. Should be good now thanks.

Comment: I've edited to clean up your equations; please confirm that what's there now is what you wanted.

Comment: I think this edit is wrong. OP please confirm.

Comment: OP might have meant $\frac{1}{2x}$, but that doesn't seem at all like the kind of problem that appears in elementary texts, where this one seems to originate.

Answer (score 0):

If my edits are correct, then you next need to apply the idea that if two things are equal, such as 
$$
C = D
$$
and $r$ is any number, then 
$$
rC = rD
$$.

In your case, part of the problem is that there are fractions; the largest denominator is 4. If you pick $r = 4$ and apply the idea above, you get

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}x-2 &= \frac{3}{4}x-3\\
4 \left[ \frac{1}{2}x-2\right] &= 4 \left[\frac{3}{4}x-3 \right] \\
\frac{4}{2}x-4 \cdot 2 &= \frac{4 \cdot 3}{4}x-4 \cdot 3  \\
2x-8 &= 3x-12
\end{align}
and you can probably do some more algebra to find the value of $x$.